# Returning a python bytearray in an HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

I have a django view that I want to return an Excel file. The code is below:

```
def get_template(request, spec_pk):
    spec = get_object_or_404(Spec, pk=spec_pk)

    response = HttpResponse(spec.get_template(), mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s_template.xls' % spec.name
    return response
```

In that example, the type of `spec.get_template()` is `<type 'bytearray'>` which contains the binary data of an Excel spreadsheet.

The problem is, when I try to download that view, and open it with Excel, it comes in as garbled binary data. I know that the `bytearray` is correct though, because if I do the following:

```
f = open('temp.xls', 'wb')
f.write(spec.get_template())
```

I can open `temp.xls` in the Excel perfectly.

I've even gone so far as to modify my view to:

```
def get_template(request, spec_pk):
    spec = get_object_or_404(Spec, pk=spec_pk)
    f = open('/home/user/temp.xls', 'wb')
    f.write(spec.get_template())
    f.close()

    f = open('/home/user/temp.xls', 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s_template.xls' % spec.name
    return response
```

And it works perfectly- I can open the xls file from the browser into Excel and everything is alright.

So my question is- what do I need to do that `bytearray` before I pass it to the `HttpResponse`. Why does saving it as binary, then re-opening it work perfectly, but passing the `bytearray` itself results in garbled data?

Comment: It is a single ASCII text of gibberish, very, very, long.

Comment: According to `file`: `ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not specific enough. You're going to have to put them through a binary diff.

Comment: Hmm... according to `cmp`: `bad.xls good.xls differ: byte 1, line 1`

Comment: Found a solution (answered below), thanks for helping though.

Comment: does it work if you do `bytearray(f.read())`?

Comment: @sebastian - It does not. `bytearray(f.read())` behaved exactly like the original byte array `spec.get_template()`. I guess the moral of the story is don't pass a `bytearray` to `HttpResponse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, through completely random (and very persistent) trial and error, I found a solution using the python `binascii` module.

This works:

```
response = HttpResponse(binascii.a2b_qp(spec.get_template()), mimetype='application/ms-excel')
```

According to the python docs for `binascii.a2b_qp`:

> Convert a block of quoted-printable data back to binary and return the binary data. More than one line may be passed at a time. If the optional argument header is present and true, underscores will be decoded as spaces.

Would love for someone to tell me why saving it as binary, then reopening it worked though.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: Cast the `bytearray` to `bytes`**

The problem is that Django's `HttpResponse` doesn't treat `bytearray` objects the same as `bytes` objects.  `HttpResponse` has a special case for `bytes` which sends them to the client as-is, but it doesn't have a similar case for `bytearray` objects.  They get handled by a catchall case which treats them as an iterable of `int`.

If you open the corrupted Excel file in a text editor, you'll probably see a bunch of ascii numbers, which are the numeric values of the bytes you were trying to return from the bytearray

Mr. Digital Flapjack gives a very complete explanation here: https://www.digitalflapjack.com/blog/2021/4/27/bytes-not-bytearrays-with-django-please